# How can we simplify the list comprehension if we have many types to compare?

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop

I'm working with the CSV file to calculate the average score of students base on their race/ethnicity.
Here is my code to read the file:

```
# read file
with open("StudentsPerformance.csv") as file:
    data = file.read().split("\n")

header = data[0]
students = data[1:]

# remove last student (empty student)
students.pop()

# get total number of students
total_student = len(students)

# split header
header = header.split(",")
subjects = header[5:]

# split each student in list
for i in range(len(students)):
    students[i] = students[i].split(",")
```

My column data file after reading it is like this (race is the second column, grades if last three-column):

```
['male', 'group D', 'high school', 'free/reduced', 'none', '74', '70', '69']
['male', 'group E', 'some high school', 'standard', 'completed', '74', '64', '60']
['male', 'group E', "associate's degree", 'free/reduced', 'none', '64', '56', '52']
['female', 'group D', 'high school', 'free/reduced', 'completed', '65', '61', '71']
['male', 'group E', "associate's degree", 'free/reduced', 'completed', '46', '43', '44']
['female', 'group C', 'some high school', 'free/reduced', 'none', '48', '56', '51']
['male', 'group C', 'some college', 'free/reduced', 'completed', '67', '74', '70']
['male', 'group D', 'some college', 'free/reduced', 'none', '62', '57', '62']
['male', 'group D', "associate's degree", 'free/reduced', 'completed', '61', '71', '73']
['male', 'group C', "bachelor's degree", 'free/reduced', 'completed', '70', '75', '74']
['male', 'group C', "associate's degree", 'standard', 'completed', '98', '87', '90']
['male', 'group D', 'some college', 'free/reduced', 'none', '70', '63', '58']
['male', 'group A', "associate's degree", 'standard', 'none', '67', '57', '53']
...
```

Then, I found type of race:

```
race = []
race_type = []
race_number = []
 
race_type = list(dict.fromkeys(race))
race_type.sort()

print(race_type)

for i in range(len(race_type)):
    race_number.append(race.count(race_type[i]))

print(race_number)
```

I have the result:

```
['group A', 'group B', 'group C', 'group D', 'group E']
[89, 190, 319, 262, 140]
```

So, I have 5 types of race: Group A: 89, Group B: 190, Group C: 319, Group D: 262, Group E: 140.

Then, I use some code to calculate the average score base on race:

```
def compute_average_score(student_group):
    return sum([score for student in student_group for score in list(map(int, student[-3:]))]) / (len(student_group) * 3)

a_group = [x for x in students if x[1] == race_type[0]]
b_group = [x for x in students if x[1] == race_type[1]]
c_group = [x for x in students if x[1] == race_type[2]]
d_group = [x for x in students if x[1] == race_type[3]]
e_group = [x for x in students if x[1] == race_type[4]]


print(round(compute_average_score(a_group), 2))
print(round(compute_average_score(b_group), 2))
print(round(compute_average_score(c_group), 2))
print(round(compute_average_score(d_group), 2))
print(round(compute_average_score(e_group), 2))
```

Then, I get the correct result:

```
62.99
65.47
67.13
69.18
72.75
```

But when I use some code to calculate the average score, I need to input the number to each group: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Then, I found that the code is not convenient if I had about ten or twenty different race types then it would probably take a lot of time and repeat code a lot. Like I need to input the number to each group: 0, 1, 2, ..., 20.

So, how can I reduce this computation for this calculation? I thought about using for loop but it doesn't seem very viable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm very confused by your code starting with the `race` related block. The `race` list you're iterating on is initially empty, so I'm not sure the rest of the code can possibly be doing anything useful. Are you supposed to be referring back to the code from the first block somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dictionary grouping idiom to group the cumulative scores and maybe the total count. So given the data:

```
>>> data = [['male', 'group D', 'high school', 'free/reduced', 'none', '74', '70', '69'],
... ['male', 'group E', 'some high school', 'standard', 'completed', '74', '64', '60'],
... ['male', 'group E', "associate's degree", 'free/reduced', 'none', '64', '56', '52'],
... ['female', 'group D', 'high school', 'free/reduced', 'completed', '65', '61', '71'],
... ['male', 'group E', "associate's degree", 'free/reduced', 'completed', '46', '43', '44'],
... ['female', 'group C', 'some high school', 'free/reduced', 'none', '48', '56', '51'],
... ['male', 'group C', 'some college', 'free/reduced', 'completed', '67', '74', '70'],
... ['male', 'group D', 'some college', 'free/reduced', 'none', '62', '57', '62'],
... ['male', 'group D', "associate's degree", 'free/reduced', 'completed', '61', '71', '73'],
... ['male', 'group C', "bachelor's degree", 'free/reduced', 'completed', '70', '75', '74'],
... ['male', 'group C', "associate's degree", 'standard', 'completed', '98', '87', '90'],
... ['male', 'group D', 'some college', 'free/reduced', 'none', '70', '63', '58'],
... ['male', 'group A', "associate's degree", 'standard', 'none', '67', '57', '53']]
```

Then grouping:

```
>>> grouper = {}
>>> for row in data:
...     group = row[1]
...     scores = map(int, row[-3:])
...     cum_score, total = grouper.get(group, (0,0))
...     grouper[group] = cum_score + sum(scores), total + 3
...
>>> grouper
{'group D': (987, 15), 'group E': (503, 9), 'group C': (860, 12), 'group A': (177, 3)}
```

Then you can calculate it like this:

```
>>> for group, (cum_score, total) in grouper.items():
...     print(f"For {group} average score is {cum_score/total}")
...
For group D average score is 65.8
For group E average score is 55.888888888888886
For group C average score is 71.66666666666667
For group A average score is 59.0
```